# Windows 8 Error

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-runtime

I'm using Windows 8 release preview, visual studio ultimate 2012 RC and the latest V4RC binaries from MVVMLight Codeplex page.

After creating a new blank metro project, adding the three MVVMLight DLLs for windows 8 and building the project, there's an error

```
Payload file 'C:\MVVMLight Binaries\Debug\Win8\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Win8\License.txt' does not exist.
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It actually turns out to be simpler than I thought - just making a blank text file in the required location is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information about your error. Otherwise you please use Nuget package manager for adding the libraries. right click on the reference tab in vs2012 you can find the option for adding the libraries from Nuget. 
Enjoy coding